# Did Camus say, "The literal meaning of life is whatever you're doing that prevents you from killing yourself"?

Tags: quotes, philosophy

I've seen this quote attributed to Camus on [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/7699175-the-literal-meaning-of-life-is-whatever-you-re-doing-that), Reddit, random memes, etc. It is a poignant rephrasing of some of Camus' philosophy of absurdism, but one that I think adds some emotional color. Camus' essay *The Myth of Sisyphus* is passionate but certainly dryer than to address the reader in such a way. Which is why for me, whether Camus said this quote is relevant: was Camus himself really this *caring*, or is that an interpretation the community has added since then?

Comment: The Myth of Sisyphus is hardly dry. I'm pretty sure that line appears in the first 25% of the book or so. Consider that the opening of the book is something to the effect of “There is only one really serious philosophical problem and that is suicide. Deciding whether or not life is worth living is to answer the fundamental question in philosophy. All other questions follow from that."

Comment: So I thought it might be in the first section *An Absurd Reasoning* but upon reading it I only found a couple similar quotes. One on page 58 says, "[...] to the extent to which I arrange my life and prove thereby that I accept its having a meaning, [...]" and on page 60, "Belief in the meaning of life always implies a scale of values, a choice, our preferences." Page numbers are from the Vintage International edition translated by Justin O'Brien.

Comment: One should note this was originally in French and it's possible a different translator rendered these as the original. I would suggest anyone else looking in this essay check the *Absurd Creation* and *Myth of Sisyphus* sections as I don't think it would be in *The Absurd Man*.